# What is the minimum number of bytes that will cause Socket.Receive to return?

Tags: c#, .net, sockets

We are using a application protocol which specifies the length indicator of the message in the first 4 bytes. Socket.Receive will return as much data as in the protocol stack at the time or block until data is available. This is why we have to continously read from the socket until we receive the number of bytes in the length indicator. The Socket.Receive will return 0 if the other side closed the connection. I understand all that.

Is there a minimum number of bytes that has to be read? The reason I ask is from the documentation it seems entirely possible that the entire length indicator (4 bytes) might not be available when socket.Receive can return. We would then have to have to keep trying. It would be more efficient to minimize the number of times we call socket.receive because it has to copy things in and out of buffers. So is it safer to get a single byte at a time to get the length indicator, is it safe to assume that 4 bytes will always be available or should we keep trying to get 4 bytes using an offset variable?

The reason that I think that there may be some sort of default minimum level is that I came across a varaible called ReceiveLowWater variable that I can set in the socket options. But this appears to only apply to BSD. [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740476%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) See SO_RCVLOWAT.

It isn't really that important but I am trying to write unit tests. I have already wrapped a standard .Net Socket behind an interface.

Comment: It's very unlikely but you should be able to deal with arbitrary-sized reads. Even 1 byte. Since it's very unlikely that this will happen most of the time you should get almost no performance hit. If those 4 bytes are not at the very start of the stream it's actually quite likely that they will be split between reads.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> is it safe to assume that 4 bytes will always be available

NO. Never. What if someone is testing your protocol with, say, telnet and a keyboard? Or over a real slow or busy connection? You *can* receive one byte at a time or a split "length indicator" over multiple `Receive()` calls. This isn't unit testing matter, it's basic socket matter that causes problems in production, especially under stressful situations.

> or should we keep trying to get 4 bytes using an offset variable?

Yes, you should. For your convenience, you can use the [`Socket.Receive()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w3xtz6a5.aspx) overload that allows you to specify a number of bytes to be read so you won't read too much. But please note it *can* return less than required, that's what the `offset` parameter is for, so it can continue to write in the same buffer:

```
byte[] lenBuf = new byte[4];
int offset = 0;

while (offset < lenBuf.Length)
{       
    int received = socket.Receive(lenBuf, offset, lenBuf.Length - offset, 0);

    offset += received;     

    if (received == 0)
    {
        // connection gracefully closed, do your thing to handle that
    }
}

// Here you're ready to parse lenBuf
```

> The reason that I think that there may be some sort of default minimum level is that I came across a varaible called ReceiveLowWater variable that I can set in the socket options. But this appears to only apply to BSD.

That is correct, the "receive low water" flag is only included for backwards compatibility and does nothing apart from throwing errors, as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740532%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), search for `SO_RCVLOWAT`:

> This option is not supported by the Windows TCP/IP provider. If this option is used on Windows Vista and later, the getsockopt and setsockopt functions fail with WSAEINVAL. On earlier versions of Windows, these functions fail with WSAENOPROTOOPT". So I guess you'll have to use the offset.

It's a shame, because it *can* enhance performance. However, as @cdleonard pointed out in a comment, the performance penalty from keeping an offset variable will be minimal, as you'l *usually* receive the four bytes at once.

Comment: Your code is basically what I am querying about. From the documentation, that overload may return less than the 4 bytes you asked for. I use the above but in a while loop to get all the data specified in the length indicator. I know that is the correct way to do it because I have come across it many times in text and other reputable SO users. But why are you suggesting that the same method will always get at least 4 bytes when we have to put that section of code in a while loop to get the body.

Comment: @uriDium you're right, I was confused with another implementation that kept `Receive()`ing until `size` bytes were read. As stated in the docs: _"If you are using a connection-oriented Socket, the Receive method will read **as much data as is available**, up to the number of bytes specified by the size parameter."_. So yeah, you'll have to do the offset magic.

Comment: but as far as you know, is there some sort of minimum water level type feature for sockets on windows platform? The same way there is for BSD systems?

Comment: Shouldn't the value passed as 3rd paramter to `Receive()` shrink in the same way, as `offset` grows? If it doesn't and more data then the buffer's size is arriving, most propably a buffer overflow will occur.

Comment: @alk thanks, you're absolutely right. I shouldn't be coding from Notepad++ and definetely not be posting untested code, although it was just to illustrate the idea. :-)

Comment: It should be mentioned, that this approach together with the example code assumes a non-blocking socket or have `SocketFlags.Partial` specified as 4th parameter to `Receive()`. Otherwise `Receive()` either returns with having read a much as specified as 3rd parameter or will cause an exception on time-out or connection  closure by the peer.

Comment: @alk it assumes a **blocking** socket to function as described. But I provided a link to MSDN, where all cases are described. There are other issues with this approach, depending on how the socket is instantiated. I didn't feel like copying the large remarks section. :-)

Comment: Ok, I'll be quiet :-)  You pointed out the essential aspect of *looping until everything had been read, even if its in steps of 1 byte*.

Comment: @alk I didn't mean to shut you up, please (keep) correct(ing) me if I'm wrong. ;-) We're all here to learn, isn't it?

Comment: You didn't. The context does. My expertise is on `C` level and I'm currently not in the mood to go through C#'s `Socket` spex at all ... so we leave this as an exercise to the OP, at least I will. ;-)

Comment: @CodeCaster could you check out my related q please: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827694/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-bytes-returned-from-socket-send

Answer (score 2):

No, there isn't a minimum buffer size, the length in the receive just needs to match the actual space.

If you send a length in four bytes before the messages actual data, the recipient needs to handle the cases where 1, 2, 3 or 4 bytes are returned and keep repeating the read until all four bytes are received and then repeat the procedure to receive the actual data.