# What is the minimum number of bytes returned from Socket.Send

Tags: c#, sockets

This is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13087268/what-is-the-minimum-number-of-bytes-that-will-cause-socket-receive-to-return) but for `Socket.Send`

Given some code like this

```
int bytesSent = socket.Send(BitConverter.GetBytes((int)0));//send 4 bytes
```

Is it possible for less than 4 to be the return value of `socket.Send` ? *before answering please read on*

The docs clearly state:

> Send synchronously sends data to the remote host specified in the Connect or Accept method and returns the number of bytes successfully sent.

The reason for asking is I am attempting to track down an issue for an inter-process socket connection (both processes running on the same server, win2012 R2) that calls `Socket.Send` as described above.

While I am familiar with safe sending/receiving of bytes over sockets **I would like some confirmation from someone who knows the internals of the native call** that could confirm the possibility of an interprocess call not sending 4 bytes and thus the `Socket.Send` returning less bytes than this. Could this be possible under load?

The code can be easily fixed by writing to the socket correctly but if someone were to look at this and say `no i would expect a **minimum** of 4 bytes for this type of call` then clearly this is not my issue

Answer (score 1):

From the [remarks section here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f3kd48xs(v=vs.110).aspx):

> In nonblocking mode, Send may complete successfully even if it sends less than the number of bytes you request. It is your application's responsibility to keep track of the number of bytes sent and to retry the operation until the application sends the requested number of bytes.

So really it comes down to whether `yourSocket.Blocking` is `true` or `false`. IIRC, this is not a concern by default, and if you haven't changed this property you should be fine.

Comment: `socket.Blocking` == true in my case (which I have not set)

Comment: @wal then I doubt this is your problem, but to be honest you could add some kind of sanity check here in about 2 minutes - don't change the code much, just essentially do `if(socket.Send(..., len) != len) throw new InvalidOperationException("Well damn, we found the problem");` (ideally also including the expected/actual numbers in the text)

Comment: Marc just as a follow up to people who may come across this thread later, you imply that you only need to safely send (ie read the result of `Socket.Send` and keep resending) if you set Blocking to false?